# "Система конфигурации не прошла инициализацию" C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

По видеоуроку на ютубе пытаюсь сделать простую заготовку под БД на C#, но при полном повторе действий выскочила **ошибка** `"System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: "Система конфигурации не прошла инициализацию""`, уточнение `"ConfigurationErrorsException:  Неизвестный раздел конфигурации connectionString. (C:\a\DBApp\DBApp\bin\Debug\DBApp.exe.Config line 6)"`. (Я пока совсем зелёная, гугл не помог и понять в чем ошибка я не могу, хотя есть подозрение на строку именно в загрузке формы, уж очень не нравится мне она, а не на ту, на что ругается).

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    <connectionString>
        <add name="DB" ConnectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\a\DBApp\DBApp\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>
    </connectionString>
</configuration>
```

Форма:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;

namespace DBApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SqlConnection SqlConnection = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString);
            SqlConnection.Open();
            if(SqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Подключение");
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs - пусто

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DBApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Пожалуйста помогите!

Comment: connectionString**s** - название элемента в конфиге должно быть во множественном числе